# How to assign project folder to a new git repository?

Tags: git

I've got a project folder on my hard-drive...it was a copy of a repository on github.

I've made quite a bit of change to the code.

But I'd like to start a new project on github with this current code on hd.

- i.e. I want it to forget about the old reposity but still keep all the code changes to be uploaded to the new git project.

Comment: When you say it's a "*copy of a repository*", do you mean it's a clone with the *.git* folder still intact/existing?

Comment: yes - it was a clone but there's lot of code changes including folder structure changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Option 1 **
delete the invisible .git repository then make a one new

if you are in Windows navigate to your folder, click view tab and check hidden items to find invisible folders

** Option 2 **

Create a new repository on github, then open your command line where the file are located and type

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git remote add origin [github rep link]
git push -u new master
```

Comment: If you wanna push the files yes.